# List Object error as :Cannot find a differ supporting object 'true'

Tags: angular

Hi I am new to angular i am try to populate the list by using ngrx store get response succefully in list page component ts but when loading that html page have error Cannot find a differ supporting object 'true' please let me how can i fix the issue

Service:

```
getSearchJobList(jobListVO):Observable<{jobs:Jobs}> {

    let url = `${environment.serviceUrl}/job/searchJob`;
    return this.http.post(url, jobListVO['payload']).switchMap((data: {jobs:Jobs}) => {
      if (data['statusFlag'] === 'Ok') {
        return Observable.of({jobs:data['paramObjectsMap']});
      } else {
        return Observable.throw({jobs:data['paramObjectsMap']['ErrorMessage']});
      }
    })
  }
```

effects

```
    @Effect() loadData$ = this.actions$.ofType(ListActions.LOAD_DATA_LIST)
    .pipe(
        switchMap((action: ListActions.LoadDataList) => this.jobService.getSearchJobList(action)),
        map((response:{jobs:Jobs}) => new ListActions.LoadDataSuccess({
            listResponse:response['jobs']['JobListVO'],
            totalCount: response['jobs']['totalRecordCount']})),
        catchError((error, caught) => {
            this.snackBar.open(error, 'Ok', {
                duration: 5000,
            });
            return Observable.of(new ListActions.LoadDataFailure())
        })
);
```

list page component

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService,
    private jobService: JobService, public store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.listResponse$ = this.store.select('listState').select('listResponse');
    console.log(this.listResponse$);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let jobListVO = Object.assign({}, {
      RequestVO: {
        FilterVO: {
          companyId: this.authService.loggedInUser()['companyId'],
          clientOrgId: this.authService.loggedInUser()['clientOrgId'], jobPriority: '',
          maxSalary: '', minSalary: '', category: '', pageSize: 10, pageIndex: 0, sortField: 'updatedDate',
          sortBy: '', keySkills: '', jobTitle: ''
        }
      }
    })


    this.store.dispatch(new ListActions.LoadDataList((jobListVO)))

  }
```

Comment: where is the code?. what are you trying so far?

Comment: Hi Please find code